# Column does not belong to table

Tags: c#, .net

I've a web site project with .NET Framework 2.0. 
The problem is `"Column 'picPath' does not belong to table."` But this error not always occurs.

Here is my code :

```
public void getAdvertisement()
{
  List<ListItem> AdvList = new List<ListItem>();
  AdvList.Add(new ListItem("@a","notList"));
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt = BLAtom.GetByDataTable("spAdvertisementGetAll", AdvList);      
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {          
      reklam1 = dt.Rows[0]["picPath"].ToString();
      reklam1Url = dt.Rows[0]["AdvUrl"].ToString();
      if (dt.Rows.Count==2)
      {
          reklam2 = dt.Rows[1]["picPath"].ToString();
          reklam2Url = dt.Rows[1]["AdvUrl"].ToString();
      }
  }     

}
```

Comment: What is `BLAtom`? Can we see the inside of `GetByDataTable`?

Comment: BLAtom is a class to execute stored procedures with parameters and return DataTable , DateSet or List.

Comment: I understand, but your issue is either with the stored procedure or the code in that method.

Comment: Without more code we cannot help you!

Comment: Please post your stored procedure code as well.

Answer (score 3):

Check your stored procedure - is it possible that the result set coming from it changes contextually?